# npm package: Sourcemap for *path* points to missing source files

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json, es6-modules, source-maps

I've created a private npm package which is built using tsc.

The package works as expected, but when I install it into other projects, Vite is giving multiple warnings that `Sourcemap for *path* points to missing source files`. The generated sourcemap files seems correct to me and they seem to link to the correct paths so I'm not sure what could be causing this issue.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2022",
        "outDir": "lib",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": false,
        "inlineSources": false,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "declarationDir": "lib"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@foo/web3",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Library for interacting with the poxi smart contract ecosystem",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "module": "lib/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "/lib"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "start": "npx tsc --watch",
    "test": "echo testing"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/foo/web3.git"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/@foo"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/foo/web3/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/foo/web3#readme",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "svelte": "^3.55.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.13.0",
    ...
  }
}
```

What could be causing these sourcemap errors?

Comment: have you found the reason for this yet? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @JudeF'do this was quite a while ago, but to the best of my memory I did not find a solution, unfortunately.